# JS/JQuery branch prediction

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the server returns a 429 "Too many request" status, the alert will pop up but the page gets changed to /ProjectCanvas. "OK" never gets printed.

```
$.post("/createProject/", null, ).fail(function() {
    alert("You are doing that too much. Please wait before trying again.");
}).done(function(data, status) {
    console.log("OK")
    window.location.href = "/ProjectCanvas/";
})
```

I think the browser wrongly predicts a successful response and starts executing it before it realizes it shouldn't be executed.

This happens on chrome and edge so far, safari works fine. Does anybody know what the issue is here?

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using ?

Comment: you are using .done methods that means your jQuery version should be >1.8. Please check

Comment: Are you returning an empty body on success ?

Comment: I am using jQuery 3.3.1. 
On succes the server returns a timestamp, e.g. 20180919-213257.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. It's more likely that one of the other requests that are occuring was successful and resulted in a redirect, or, the redirect is being caused by some other action entirely, such as an anchor click or a form submit. Branch prediction isn't really a thing when it comes to ajax requests.

Comment: It seems you were right, another post request also had a window.location change in it's callback, oops! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The param in the jQuery post method is callback function.

```js
$.post("/createProject/", function() {
   var defer = $.Deferred();

   if(status === "success"){
     defer.promise(data);
   }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log("OK")
    window.location.href = "/ProjectCanvas/";
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("You are doing that too much. Please wait before trying again.");
  })
```

Comment: Yes, but     window.location.href = "/ProjectCanvas/" should never be executed if an error occurs

Comment: OK can you post the sample response from server? I think I know the fix.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests`  
`Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 19:37:30 GMT`  
`Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.0`  
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`  
`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`  
`Content-Length: 78`   
`Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie`  
`Content-Language: nl`  

`/createProject/, You are doing that too much. Please wait before trying again.`

Comment: you are not expecting JSON response? In the response you should get the errorCode: 429?

Comment: I actually ignore the response body, it's not JSON, just a simple string. I want to know whether the server returns an error or not. My previous comment was the full HTTP response (not well formatted).

Comment: Print data and status in the 1st alert and see what you are getting. i updated my answer.

Comment: data: `20180919-220836`
  
status: `success`

It doesn't print anything on error

Comment: so you mean on 429 error you won't get status:success?

Comment: I figured it out, the error was in a whole other function, thanks for helping!